# How do I calculate the number of days in this year in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can i calculate the number of days in a year for any calendar, not just gregorian.
I have tried this

`NSUInteger *days = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];`

but that gives me the number of days in the current month instead of the number of days in the current year.

Comment: It is not actually giving you the number of days in the current month. It actually gives you the possible range of values for days in the year with is from 1 to 31. There is no date which could have a day number of 32.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution that works. What I do is first calculate the number of months in the year and then for each month calculate the number of days for that month.

The code looks like this:

```
NSUInteger days = 0;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSUInteger months = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                                   inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                  forDate:today].length;
for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
    components.month = i;
    NSDate *month = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    days += [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                           inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                          forDate:month].length;
}

return days;
```

It is not as neat as I would have hoped for but it will work for any calendar such as the ordinary gregorian one or the islamic one.

Answer (score 8):

In general you may use number of days between 1st day of the year and 1st day of the next year. Here's the code that illustrates this approach

```
- (NSDate *)firstDateOfYear:(NSInteger)year
{
    NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dc.year = year;
    dc.month = 1;
    dc.day = 1;
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dc];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfDaysInYear:(NSInteger)year
{
    NSDate *firstDateOfYear = [self firstDateOfYear:year];
    NSDate *firstDateOfNextYear = [self firstDateOfYear:year + 1];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:firstDateOfYear toDate:firstDateOfNextYear options:0];
    return [components day];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know objective-c but it is a simple algorithm to determine if it is a leap year.

```
if ( year % 400 == 0 )
   then 366 // Leap Year
else if ( year % 100 == 0 )
   then 365 // Non-Leap Year
else if ( year % 4 == 0 )
   then 366 // Leap Year
else
   365 // Non-Leap Year
```

Or if you want a little less verbose version

```
if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
   then 366 // Leap Year
else
   365 // Non-Leap Year
```

Comment: Please be mindful that this algorithm will break for years before 1582, before leap years where introduced ;-)

Comment: This is true. You would have to add a check to make sure the year is after 1582. If you need to take that into account.

Comment: This is not realy what I was asking for, because it will only work for the gregorian calendar.

Comment: Also this should be noted that it only works on the Gregorian calendar . So you may find it helpful but I don't think it 100% solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anybody is still interested in this thread, but is another possible solution:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startOfYear;
NSTimeInterval lengthOfYear;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
            startDate:&startOfYear
             interval:&lengthOfYear
              forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *endOfYear = [startOfYear dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthOfYear];
NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                     fromDate:startOfYear
                                       toDate:endOfYear
                                      options:0];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInThisYear = [comp day];
```

using only 2 calls to `NSCalendar`.

Comment: hey. Could this make your solution even better if we simply divide length of year by number of seconds in a day?

Comment: @Olex: How would you compute the "length of year"?  Also the number or seconds in a day is not a fixed value. In regions with daylight saving time, a day can have 23 or 25 hours, when DST starts or ends. Moreover, the question asks for the number of day in *any* calendar, not only the Gregorian. So the number of days in a year may be different from 365.

Comment: Martin, you already compute the lengthOfYear (which is in seconds). And the number of seconds in a day is 24 * 60 * 60. DST won't affect this approach as 23 + 25 = 48 = 24 + 24. Other calendars should work too because you compute the length of the year in a specific calendar. A rounding to a nearest integer may be needed though.

Comment: @Olex: One cannot assume that there are always two DST transitions in the year (one forward and one back). For example, in 1976 in Portugal/Lisbon the clocks were only turned back in September (they changed the time zone from UTC to UTC+1).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` selector which is meant to (and I quote [official Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:)): *Returns, as an NSDateComponents object using specified components, the difference between two supplied dates.* ?

Also read [this post](http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2008/01/25/happy-fun-leopard-bug-time-nscalendar/) that clarifies the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: This could do, but how should I describe the date "last day of the year"

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html Check out the example at the bottom of that page, if you work with the NSDateComponents that might work for all calendars.

Comment: I thought about this and I don't think it will work because it will take me back to square one and I'll have the same problem again.

Comment: I also updated my original answer with another link, that explains the odd behavior you are getting ;) It is something that only came into existence since Leopard.

Comment: This helped me to understand why my original approach didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like Jason Coco's answer uses exactly this approach

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you want you have to find the range of days in a month and months in a year for a specific calendar. This function will do what you need for any calendar that uses day/month/year units (or has some equivalent mapped):

```
NSInteger getDaysInYear(NSDate* date)
{
    // Get the current calendar
    NSCalendar* c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Find the range for days and months in this calendar
    NSRange dayRange = [c rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:date];
    NSRange monthRange = [c rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:date];

    // Get the year from the suppled date
    NSDateComponents* yearComps = [c components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    NSInteger thisYear = [yearComps year];

    // Create the first day of the year in the current calendar
    NSUInteger firstDay = dayRange.location;
    NSUInteger firstMonth = monthRange.location;
    NSDateComponents* firstDayComps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [firstDayComps setDay:firstDay];
    [firstDayComps setMonth:firstMonth];
    [firstDayComps setYear:thisYear];
    NSDate* firstDayDate = [c dateFromComponents:firstDayComps];

    // Create the last day of the year in the current calendar
    NSUInteger lastDay = dayRange.length;
    NSUInteger lastMonth = monthRange.length;
    NSDateComponents* lastDayComps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [lastDayComps setDay:lastDay];
    [lastDayComps setMonth:lastMonth];
    [lastDayComps setYear:thisYear];
    NSDate* lastDayDate = [c dateFromComponents:lastDayComps];

    // Find the difference in days between the first and last days of the year
    NSDateComponents* diffComps = [c components:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                       fromDate:firstDayDate
                                         toDate:lastDayDate
                                        options:0];

    // We have to add one since this was subtraction but we really want to
    // give the total days in the year
    return [diffComps day] + 1;
}
```

If you want to specify this year, you can call it simply as `getDaysInYear([NSDate date]);`, or you could create a date from specific year/other components and pass that. You could also very easily re-implement it as a method call.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution found for this problem using SWIFT 5.3 and Xcode 12.

Put it into playgrounds, call the checkLeapYear function passing a year into it and play around.

```
func checkLeapYear(year: Int) {
    if year % 4 == 0{
        if year % 100 == 0 {
            if year % 400 == 0{
                print("\(year) is a Leap Year!")
            } else {
                print("\(year) is NOT a Leap Year!")
            }
        } else {
            print("\(year) is a Leap Year!")
        }
    } else {
        print("\(year) is NOT a Leap Year!")
    }
}
```

The algorithm is quite tricky so I suggest you use the following logic when performing it on your own:

1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2.
   Otherwise, go to step 5.
2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3.
   Otherwise, go to step 4.
3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4.
   Otherwise, go to step 5.
4. The year is a leap year.
5. The year is not a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, those are involved solutions.  Just create a date of February 29 of the current year and see if it's converted to march first or not.

```
-(BOOL)isLeapYear {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDate currentCalendar] components:componentFlags fromDate:self];
    components.month = 2;
    components.day = 29;

    NSDate *date = [[NSDate currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
    return (date.month == 2 && date.day == 29);
}
```

**  Note, some of these items like date.month and date.day relay on other methods not shown, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: This would be specific to the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Another example in Swift 3:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = Date() // use any date in this year
if let yearInterval = calendar.dateInterval(of: Calendar.Component.year, for: date),
   let daysInYear = calendar.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.day], from: yearInterval.start, to: yearInterval.end).day
{
    print(daysInYear)
}
```

In Objective-C:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDate* startOfYear = nil;
NSTimeInterval yearDuration = 0;
if ([calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear startDate:&startOfYear interval:&yearDuration forDate:d
]) {
    NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:startOfYear toDate:[startOfYear dateByAddingTimeInterval:yearDuration] options:0];
    NSInteger daysInYear = daysComponents.day;
    NSLog(@"Days in year: %ld", daysInYear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 extension:

```
extension Date {
    public func isLeapYear() -> Bool {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: self)

        guard let year = components.year else { return false }

        return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                        inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:date];
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the answer provided by William Clemens but in Objective C:

```
                    int year;
                    int yearCode;

                    if ( year % 400 == 0 )
                        {yearCode = 366;} // Leap Year
                    else if ( year % 100 == 0 )
                    {
                        {yearCode = 365;} // Non Leap Year
                    }
                    else if ( year % 4 == 0 )
                    {
                         {yearCode = 366;} // Leap Year
                    }
                    else
                    {yearCode = 365;} // Non-Leap Year
```