# How to convert today's date into Day of the Year for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to do this in Xcode...

Today's Date = Day of the year

October 13th = 303 (I think)
January 1st = 1
December 31st = 365

NSDate to get todays date, then I'm out of idea =(

Comment: Possible dupe of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080927/how-do-you-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-for-a-specific-date-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"D"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"Today: %@", date);
NSLog(@"Date Formatted: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);

[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`