# iOS How to get day number of the year?

Tags: ios, numbers, nsdate, days, leap-year

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you calculate the day of the year for a specific date in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080927/how-do-you-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-for-a-specific-date-in-objective-c)

I need to get the day number of the year and don't know which would be the best aproach.

Example:

21-jan-2012 -> 21

2-feb-2012 -> 33

2-mar-2012 -> 62

2-mar-2011 -> 61

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a valid question to a valid logic need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at NSTimeInterval. You can get the seconds elapsed between two dates:

```
NSTimeInterval secondsElapsed = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
```

So your firstDate can be the beginning of the year. Then you can just divide by 3600*24 (seconds per day) to get the days.

Comment: This is actually not correct, I'm new to the topic but using NSCalendar (or NSDateFormatter) would be the safer approach:
http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW7) also cover this:

"If you instead want to know what number day of the year it is you can use the ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate: method of the NSCalendar class."

Answer (score 22):

I'm a little late for the party but anyway, here it goes:

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"DDD"];
 NSInteger dayInYear = [[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] integerValue];
 NSLog(@"today is %d. day in year", dayInYear);
```

result for 14.jun.2012: *today is 166. day in year*

EDIT: i was amazed that there was no easy-to-find example on Google.

You could also use format `@"DD"` to get day in month or `@"D"` to get day in week.

EDIT2: Just a note: creating `NSDateFormatter` can be quite *expensive* operation. If your class uses this function frequently you might want to create a static formatter ivar.

Comment: +1 for using NSDateFormatter to solve the problem. I love having two ways to do something.

Comment: Thanks! +1 back at you :) I agree, more ways to do something is certainly fun.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the below solution You have to use **timeIntervalSinceDate**: for this

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-01-01"];
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date]; 
    NSLog(@"date %@ ", date2);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate *dt = [dateFormat dateFromString:theDate];


    NSTimeInterval diffDays = [dt timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"Date %f ^^^^ ", diffDays/(24*60*60));
```

Answer (score -3):

At first You create a Dictionnary like :

```
[Jan => 30,
Feb =>  28,
 ...]
```

With all days per month.

- Secondly with your date like : 13 June 2012.
- You'll add all value of the month before june (a while on your dictionnary).
- And finish by add the day (here : 13).

Comment: what about leap years? this is not a good practice