# Date offset from beginning of year

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to know How do I find the date offset from beginning of year in iOS. I want a function which will take the date as an input and tell me the number of days passed.

For ex Jan 2 = 2nd Day of year and Feb 14 = 45th Day of Year

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: This is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080927/how-do-you-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-for-a-specific-date-in-objective-c