# NSDate day of the year (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

How might the day number of the year be found with swift?  Is there a simple way that I'm not seeing, or do I have to find the number of seconds from Jan 1 to the current date and divide by the number of seconds in a day?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a translation of the answer to [How do you calculate the day of the year for a specific date in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080927/how-do-you-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-for-a-specific-date-in-objective-c) to Swift.

**Swift 2:**

```
let date = NSDate() // now
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let day = cal.ordinalityOfUnit(.Day, inUnit: .Year, forDate: date)
print(day)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let date = Date() // now
let cal = Calendar.current
let day = cal.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: date)
print(day)
```

This gives `1` for the first day in the year, and `56 = 31 + 25` for today (Feb 25).

> ... or do I have to find the number of seconds from Jan 1 to the current date
>   and divide by the number of seconds in a day

This would be a wrong approach, because a day does not have a fixed
number of seconds (transition from or to Daylight Saving Time).

Comment: why does your method returns 56 mine 55 ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: See updated answer: This method returns 1 for the first day in the year.

Comment: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().ordinalityOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitYear, forDate: NSDate() )

Comment: perfect thank you, ordinalityOfUnit, no wonder I couldn't find it

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: Yes of course (and you could write an extension for it, SCNR :) – I prefer multiple shorter statements in the answer, as they are better readable.

Comment: when I run this I get 55, shouldn't i get 56?

Comment: @zbnrg: I get 56 (and Leonardo as well, as it seems).

Comment: @Martin R That's correct 55 using mine and 56 using yours

Comment: hm, okay, well it works for my purposes anyhow, thank you both

Comment: Not working in Swift 2, compiler throws error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: @mrtn.lxo: Yes, the definition of calendar units changed with Swift 2. I have  extended the answer for Swift 2, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 16):

Swift 3

```
extension Date {
    var dayOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
}
```

use like

```
Date().dayOfYear
```

Answer (score 4):

Not at all !!! All you have to do is to use NSCalendar to help you do your calendar calculations as follow:

```
let firstDayOfTheYear  = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: NSDate()), month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!   // "Jan 1, 2015, 12:00 AM"

let daysFromJanFirst = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: firstDayOfTheYear, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil).day   // 55

let secondsFromJanFirst = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: firstDayOfTheYear, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil).second   // 4,770,357
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of days since your date like this:

```
let date = NSDate() // your date

let days = cal.ordinalityOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitYear, forDate: date)

println(days)
```

Comment: It is object of NSCalendar