# How can I get the current day of the current year in integer in objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponentsformatter

Hello dear I want to retrieve the number of day in the year e.g today is 10th April and I know its 10th day of the month but what if I want the number of the day of the year like today is 99th day of the year.

This is what I have done so far:

```
NSInteger todaydaysyear;

NSDateFormatter *yearlyDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[yearlyDay setDateFormat:@"dd-yyyy"];
NSDate *currentdateyear = [NSDate date];
NSString *cureentdatestryear = [yearlyDay stringFromDate:currentdateyear];
NSDate *startDateyear = [yearlyDay dateFromString:cureentdatestryear];

NSDateComponents *componentsyear = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:startDateyear];
todaydaysyear = [componentsyear day];
NSLog(@"here is the day of the year e.g 99th day but not prints month day why%ld", (long)todaydaysyear);
```

Prints: 10 the current day of the month

What I want: 99th day of the year the current day of the ear count.

Ans: [How do you calculate the day of the year for a specific date in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080927/how-do-you-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-for-a-specific-date-in-objective-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695408/1042817

Comment: @Rocky nothing in the link you posted answers OP's question

Comment: @Larme I think you got my point tjanx

Comment: @Larme how can I store in variable the current day and release is not working in

Comment: @Larme would you give me an answer with a variable store the current day in objective c please

Comment: That's old code without ARC, there is an updated answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920922/1801544

Comment: " with a variable store the current day" I don't understand that. There is a `[NSDate date]` at some point, that's "now" (or you can replace it with the date you want).

Comment: @Larme than bro you made my day would you give me updated answer so I can accept it

Comment: I still didn't understand what's wrong with previous answer, I didn't get your last question in comment. But as far as I can see, your question is a duplicate and I'd recommend you to upvote the answer that helped you there.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), the day of year is denoted by `D` (1..3 digits). Remember to use 3 digits, because year can have 365 days

```
[yearlyDay setDateFormat:@"DDD-yyyy"];
```

Output:

> @"100-2018"

If you want to store it as integer, try

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"DDD"];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSInteger dayOfYear = [string integerValue];
```

Comment: No bro this gives me 10, but I want to get 99th

Comment: the ?'er need as jan01 - 10 apr == 99 days

Comment: yes bro exactly

Comment: but I don't wan to make a loop I just want to retrieve the current date

Comment: @iOSDeveloper today is the 100th day of year and that's what I'm getting as an output. Remember to use capital `D` instead of `d`

Comment: This is the best solution imo

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
//Assuming your calendar is initiated like this
NSCalendar *_calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSInteger yearlyDay;
//Fetch the weekOfYear number
NSInteger weekOfYear = [_calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
weekOfYear--;
//Fetch the weekDay number
NSInteger weekDay = [_calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
yearlyDay = weekOfYear*7 + weekDay;
NSLog(@"%d", yearlyDay);
```

or this.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian =
    [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSUInteger dayOfYear =
    [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                         inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear forDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSLog(@"%d", dayOfYear);
```