# How to test until condition is met?

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem with following algorithm, What should be done to resolve this problem 
I type  a year if the year is not a leap year I will need to type again untill the typed year is a leap year.

```
    int year = 0;        
    BOOL yearC;

    NSLog(@"Enter the year to be tested;");
    scanf ("%i", &year);
    yearC = ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 !=0)|| year % 400 == 0);
    if ( yearC  )
             NSLog (@"It's a leap year.");
    else 
    {
        NSLog (@"Nope, it's not a leap year.");
       scanf ("%i", &year);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `while`-loop?

Comment: use a while loop to solve the assignment

Comment: I would use a loop for this. In this case "while" should do the trick. ;-) Never give up, keep on improving! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078372/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-days-in-this-year-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

You can use [while loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html), code bellow should work for you :)

Just set a starting value for yearC then repeat the while block until yearC is set to YES (is a leap year)

```
BOOL yearC = NO;

while(!yearC){
    NSLog(@"Enter the year to be tested;");
    scanf ("%i", &year);
    yearC = ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 !=0)|| year % 400 == 0);
    if ( yearC )
        NSLog (@"It's a leap year.");
    else {
        NSLog (@"Nope, it's not a leap year."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaaand: Homework's done.