# How to find out whether current year leap year or not in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

How to get current year from `NSDate` and how to find out whether that year is leap year or not in Objective-C?

Comment: Extract year using `NSDateComponent`, if remainder when divided by 4 is 0 then it's a leap year.

Comment: @iNoob: That is not correct. 1900 was not a leap year in the Gregorian calendar. And it might be completely different in other calendars.

Comment: @MartinR, sorry didnt know that, but `NSDateComponents` takes a value for `NSCalendar` type won't that help ?

Comment: There is a nice answer on the simulare question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2078633/309925

Comment: there's always google to help you out

Comment: @AshokKumarIOS: You you actually want to know if the year is a leap year, or do you want to know the number of days in the current year?

Comment: @MartinR I just want to know the Whether the current year is leap year or not..Thanks..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
- (BOOL)isYearLeapYear:(NSDate *) aDate {
    NSInteger year = [self yearFromDate:aDate];
    return (( year%100 != 0) && (year%4 == 0)) || year%400 == 0;
}

- (NSInteger)yearFromDate:(NSDate *)aDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy";
    NSInteger year = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate] integerValue];
    return year;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this is valid only for the Gregorian calender (but that might be sufficient for the OP).

Comment: Since iOS 6 a leapMonth property exists in NSDateComponents. I have not been able to get it to work though :( Apart from the home brewn formula a way to do it through Cocoa is to calculate the number of days in the year, or the month February.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia:

```
if year is divisible by 400 then
   is_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 100 then
   not_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 4 then
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find the year using NSDateComponant,and if you get the year divide it by 4 if divide then this is leap year.

Comment: also same comment is there..! so please review it

Comment: That is not enough (divisible by four).  See Filip's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"dat eis %@",date);

    NSDateFormatter *dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateF setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    NSString *dateS = [dateF stringFromDate:date ];
    NSLog(@"date is %@",dateS);

    int myInt = [dateS intValue];

    if(myInt%4== 0)

    {
        NSLog(@"Its a leap year ");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not A leap year");
    }
```